# Lagrange multiplier with two constraints problem...

Tags: calculus

[image]

Here’s my working so far but not sure how to proceed after this.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the expression for x,y and z in terms of lambda and miu, right? Now substitute them in the constraint equations, you will get two new equations, which will get you the values for lambda and miu.